# Row wise column subtraction causing error I don't understand

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns of numbers, lots of rows. I'm simply trying to subtract one column from another row wise then append that result to a new column in the same df. When I select the column with iloc I get the desired result, but when I select the column by its column name and perform the calculation the result gives the error that follows.

```
df_2['DK1_NP'] =  df_2['flow_in_DK1'] - df_2['flow_out_DK1']

Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column DK1_NP
```

The columns in the df contain data of the same type and the lengths match,. However, this next line works fine, can someone explain why?

```
df_2['DK1_NP'] = df_2.iloc[:,16] - df_2.iloc[:,15] # this works fine
```

print out of `df_2.head()`

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

output from `df_2.columns`

```
MultiIndex([(   'FI > SE1',),
        (   'SE1 > FI',),
        (   'FI > SE3',),
        (   'SE3 > FI',),
        (    'FI > EE',),
        (    'EE > FI',),
        (   'FI > FRE',),
        (   'FRE > FI',),
        ( 'flow_in_FI',),
        ('flow_out_FI',)],
       )
```

Comment: you have a typo, it should be - ```df_2['DK1_NP'] =  df_2['flow_in_DK1'] - df_2['flow_out_DK1']```

Comment: yes thanks, corrected. But to be clear, this isn't the reason I get the error

Comment: can you post the output of `df_2.head()` ?

Comment: I get an error now too...

Comment: can you add output from `df_2.columns`?

Comment: also added in edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252595/discussion-between-tom-edwards-and-nithish08).

Comment: We cannot guess what's in your `df_2`. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.